# Unexpected Redefinition of variable in iterator to read all list element

Tags: java, arrays, list, iterator

As part of an exercise I made 3 objects from a pre-given class called MarriedPerson

I made an array instance for these 3 objects, then defined them manually due to their different properties.
The purpose of the exercise was to add the entire array in a List, then read the list using Iterator object, 
but I am getting an unexpected error in this line 
`MarriedPerson mp = (MarriedPerson)iter.next();`

Error Code:Variable mp is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
*(sorry for this kind of question but I am a beginner in Java)*

```
import java.util.*;
abstract class MyTester {
  public static void main(String[] args){
   MarriedPerson[] mp = new MarriedPerson[3];
   mp[0] = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Betty", 31, 980.5f, Person.FEMALE, 3); 
   mp[1] = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Kirk", 31, 2080f, Person.MALE, 2); 
   mp[3] = new MarriedPerson("Tront", "Sonia", 31, 600f, Person.FEMALE, 0); 
   List<MarriedPerson> mpList = new ArrayList<MarriedPerson>(3);
   for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
        mpList.add(mp[i]);

   Iterator iter = mpList.iterator();
   while(iter.hasNext()){
        MarriedPerson mp = (MarriedPerson)iter.next();
        mp.printInfo();
   }

   for( int i=0; i<3; i++ )
        mp[i].printInfo();
   mp[0].setSalary(mp[1]); 
   mp[0].printInfo(); 
   mp[0].setSalary(mp[2]); 
   mp[0].printInfo(); 
   mp[0].setSalary(mp[1].getSalary()); 
   mp[0].printInfo();
  }
}
```

Comment: mp[3] should be changed to mp[2] in line 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not notice this typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I am getting an unexpected error in this line  MarriedPerson mp =
>   (MarriedPerson)iter.next();
>
> Error Code:Variable mp is already defined in method
>   main(java.lang.String[])

Because you already have an array named `mp`, which has a larger scope than the temporary variable `mp` you defined in your while loop.

As the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4) states:

> It is a compile-time error if the name of a local variable v is
>   redeclared as a local variable of the directly enclosing method,
>   constructor, or initializer block within the scope of v;

Like this is not valid:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

This is not too:

```
 MarriedPerson[] mp = new MarriedPerson[3];

 /.../
 Iterator iter = mpList.iterator();
 while(iter.hasNext()){
     MarriedPerson mp = (MarriedPerson)iter.next(); //hey already an array named mp
     mp.printInfo();
 }
```

To get rid of this, you could give another name to the married person you get with your iterator:

```
while(iter.hasNext()){
    MarriedPerson marriedPerson = (MarriedPerson)iter.next();
    marriedPerson.printInfo();
}
```

Also don't use a raw `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<MarriedPerson> iter = mpList.iterator();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!!
By the way if its not too much trouble could you explain to me what's the difference ? (raw Iterator)

Comment: @niCk If you look at your code, you needed to cast the value returned by `it.next()` to a `MarriedPerson`. Nothing can prevent somebody to do `String mp = (String)iter.next();` and you'll get a `ClassCastException` at runtime. Using a generic one, you preserve the type-safety at compile time and the previous example will produce a compilation error. Now, you know that `next()` returns a `MarriedPerson` and hence you could just do  `MarriedPerson mp = iter.next();`.

Comment: I suggest you to read this for more infos about generics (as it's hard to tell all the benefits here): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Local variable "mp" is already defined in main method:

```
 MarriedPerson[] mp = new MarriedPerson[3]
```

So you cannot declare a local variable with the same name:

```
 Iterator iter = mpList.iterator();
 while(iter.hasNext()){
        MarriedPerson mp = (MarriedPerson)iter.next(); // not allowed
        mp.printInfo();
   }
```

Change the variable name inside the loop and make it unique:

```
while(iter.hasNext()){
        MarriedPerson person = (MarriedPerson)iter.next();
        person.printInfo();
}
```

Or use Java's "for-each" loop construct which uses the underlying iterator mechanism:

```
for (MarriedPerson person : mpList) {
        person.printInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the variable mp twice.

Once as:

MarriedPerson mp = (MarriedPerson)iter.next();

Then as:

MarriedPerson[] mp = new MarriedPerson[3];